# programming workflow  : which one ? passing argument from function to function or passing the output as argument to other function?

Tags: python, function, workflow, arguments

i'm looking for the comparison of these option workflows (#1 and #2 as below). 
So i'm using function xx() which is calling another x() function. This is generic programming workflow (the code is python syntax but the flow logic can apply to any other language).

So the option#1 show workflow where i have to pass argument from one function to another, while in #2 i don't have to pass all the argument , just the ouput of first function as argument to the second function.

## option #1 :

```
def x(a):
    <code>
    return  value

def xx(a):
    x=x(a)
    <code>
    return value

print xx(a)
```

## option #2 :

```
def x(a):
    <code>
    return  value

def xx(x):
    <code>
    return value

x=x(a)
print xx(x)
```

It's just simple example. What i found so far in option#1 that every argument passed into x() has to pass into xx() as well. example when passing a lot argument (this is basic example where i don't use * or ** for passing multiple argument):

## option#1

```
def x(a1,a2,….a100):
    <code>
    return value

def xx(b1,b2,…..b100):
    x=x(b1,b2,….b100)
    <code>
    return value

print xx(45,'test',....,999)
```

## option#2

```
def x(a1,a2,….a100):
    <code>
    return value

def xx(x):
    <code>
    return value

x=x(45,'test',....,999)
print xx(x)
```

in #1 , i have to do a lot of 'typing' to input the argument to pass in def xx() , in otherhand, #2 is cleaner ,esier to debug. So what do u guyz think about these workflows? does workflow#1 have some advantages? is #2 generally better ? what do you think? what reason to choose #1 or #2.

Comment: The answer to this, of course, is to use OOP.

Comment: thanx , i've modified code so it's not oop style. The previous example maybe not the correct one. I made it more generic.

Answer (score 3):

`select_color_from_obj` seems to be an unnecessary function. You could just call

```
get_obj().color()
```

Also if `get_obj()` is in the same scope as the other code you could just access the object directly with

```
obj.color()
```

However if the definition of `obj` appears in a different file, then `get_obj` may be useful.

Comment: Hi thanx for answering my question, yes that's right but that's not what i'm looking for :), i'm looking for the comparison for two workflow. Try another more generic example :

Comment: I'm not too sure what these workflows are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to build another layer of abstraction on top of OO? What organization are these schemes adding that is not found in public method interfaces? Perhaps a more elaborated usage might be more insightful.

Comment: Sorry i might have posted unproper example in my first post ... so i've just modified the question to be more specific. You can re-review it if you got time. THanx a lot.